# Why can't symfony find my auto-loaded class?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, autoload

I'm trying to use the [php-ga](http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/) third-party library in my symfony project.  I've installed the library in `apps/<app>/lib`, cleared the cache, and the third-party files are appearing as I would expect in **config_autoload.yml.php**:

```
'tracker' => 'C:/wamp/www/apps/api/lib/php-ga/GoogleAnalytics/Tracker.php',
'transaction' => 'C:/wamp/www/apps/api/lib/php-ga/GoogleAnalytics/Transaction.php',
...
```

However, when I try to use the classes in an action under the same app like so:

```
use UnitedPrototype\GoogleAnalytics;

public function executeNew(sfWebRequest $request)
{
   $tracker = new GoogleAnalytics\Tracker(...);
   ...
```

I get an error saying it can't resolve the class:

> Fatal error: Class 'UnitedPrototype\GoogleAnalytics\Tracker' not found in C:\wamp\www\apps\api\modules\encoding\actions\actions.class.php

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony's autoloader can not load namespaced classes properly. I think you should move the ga lib to `lib/vendor/php-ga` and use it's own autoloader in `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php` (like `require_once __DIR__ . '/../lib/vendor/php-ga/autoload.php'`).

Comment: Good info!  It turns out that (my version of) symfony also expects autoloaders to be arrays, so I had to [convert php-ga's autoloader to a class with a static method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php#84086).  After that it worked, though - thank you!

Comment: Glad to help, but I think it's nothing to do with symfony. You should put any vendor lib under `lib/vendor` which dir is excluded from symfony's autoloading mechanism by default (since v1.3).

Comment: I did move it to `lib/vendor`, and the classes disappeared from *config_autoload.yml.php*.  However, symfony enumerates all autoloaders in *sfAutoloadAgain.class.php* with `spl_autoload_functions()` and treats the value as an array.

Comment: Hi @ladenedge, I believed I have similiar issue with you but I am not running symfony. Can you show me your converted php-ga's autoloader to a class with a static method as I encountered blank page.