# "don't find static file" when I uploaded my files from Windows to Unix

Tags: php

I have integrated a PHP API in one of my CMS in Windows Environment and it works.
However, when I uploaded the changes in Unix environment, it does not work.

As I have uses quite a few "include" and "use" in the php, I suspect it might be due to how Windows and Unix handle directory path.

I tried echo DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant and found out there is different i.e. Windows uses "\" and Unix uses "/".
However, I did a search online this shouldn't affect the namespace.

Hence, I am not sure how should I go about debugging this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us some code examples and the errors messages you get?

Comment: I believed my case is similiar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238401/why-cant-symfony-find-my-auto-loaded-class

Based on the user comment, he mentioned that he convert php-ga's autoloader to a class with a static method

However, I tried add a static beside the function keyword but now my script hang. Below is the original script. 
https://github.com/thomasbachem/php-ga/blob/master/src/autoload.php

I wonder do I need to edit other part of the code to convert correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very high chance that the problem is case sensitivity, because Windows isn't but UNIX is.

The only way to really check is to have a look and make sure the filename used in your code is EXACTLY the same as the filename on the disk.